# Encrypting SQL Lite Database for Cordova Windows 10 (Surface 3)

Tags: sql, .net, cordova, encryption

I am trying to use SQL Cipher for Encrypting my database which is being consumed by Cordova Based Hybrid App. It works fine in iOS and Android but fails for Windows 10 Build

Officially SQL Cipher doesn't support Cordova for Windows. Is there any way I can encrypt by SQL Lite database and build for Cordova - Windows ?